# Вычислить сумму элементов массива, находящихся между минимальным и первым положительным элементами

Tags: c++, массивы

Постоянно выдает 0 или рандомные числа. Не знаю в чем беда, уже все пробовал.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"
#include "iomanip"
using namespace std;
void main()
{
setlocale(0, "");
const int n = 5;
float P = 1, A[n], t = 0;
int i, k = 0, first, last, j,buf;
cout << "Введите " << n << " элементов массива" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> A[i];
cout << "Сформированный массив" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << A[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
//a)определить количество отрицательных элементов массива, значение которых по модулю <10
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (A[i] > 0);
    else
        if (A[i] <10 && A[i]>-10) k++;
cout << "Кол-во отрицательных элементов= " << k << endl;


// б)вычислить сумму элементов массива, находящихся между минимальным и первым положительным элементами;
float sum = 0;
int  ipol, imin;
imin = 0;
ipol = -1;
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    if (A[i] > 0)
    {
        ipol = i;break;
    }
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    if (A[i]<A[imin]) imin = i;
if (ipol > -1)
{
    int istart = (ipol < imin) ? ipol : imin;
    int iend = (ipol < imin) ? imin : ipol;
    for (i = istart + 1;i < iend;i++)
        sum += A[i];
    cout << "Сумма равна  " << sum << endl;

}
else cout << "Нет положительных элементов " << endl;
```

}

Comment: Судя по условию `if (A[i] > 0) sum += A[i];` вы подсчитываете только элементы больше нуля, так задумано?

Comment: нет, не обязательно уже)

Comment: У вас явно что-то не так **не здесь**. Доведенный до компилируемого состояния код нормально работает: https://ideone.com/Dp1ig0

Comment: @Harry а что к примеру может быть не так?

Comment: А я знаю? Покажите весь код...

Comment: @Harry все залил полностью

Comment: Все работает. Ошибка только одна - вы считаете 0 отрицательным. *Постоянно выдает 0 или рандомные числа* - не увидел. У вас лишние переменные, или странный метод поиска отрицательных элементов, по модулю меньших 10, но это не влияет на вычисление суммы... Можно улучшить алгоритм, но вопрос не в этом. Я не вижу никаких "рандомных значений"...

Comment: @Harry спасибо я понял почему не работало... ошибка в моей голове была, не так задание понял...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ну раз не здесь то только n, может быть не весь массив проходите?

может приведёте входные данные, да и кода чуть выше приведённого. у меня суммы вроде бы правильно находит.

у меня работает. единственно правил работу с консолью ( язык другой ). сам алгоритм верный вроде. а вот как С++ переводит строки во float, может проблема там? Harry в коментах пишет что доводил до компиляции - до того как увидел работу с консолью.

Comment: не а, весь массив проходит..

Comment: @parapozner все добавил